# Unable to apply different CSS classes to each data set in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi we are looking apply different CSS classes to each data set, which is generated by the foreach loop data.

following is what we've tried, but no luck, can you please go throuh my code and correct it

```
            <ul class="imagehover-maindiv">
            <li class="hovermaindiv">

                @foreach (var a in Model.publicShowModelProfileForUI)
                {

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                        <div class="hoverchilddiv bg-img1">
                            <img class="" src="~/Files/ProfilePics/@a.profilepic" width="80" height="80" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="overlay-text">
                            <h6 class="overlay-text-clr">@a.profilename</h6>
                        </div>
                        }

                    if (i == 2)
                        {
                            <div class="hoverchilddiv bg-img2">
                                <img class="" src="~/Files/ProfilePics/@a.profilepic" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                <h6 class="overlay-text-clr">@a.profilename</h6>
                            </div>
                        }
                        if (i == 3)
                        {
                            <div class="hoverchilddiv bg-img3">
                                <img class="" src="~/Files/ProfilePics/@a.profilepic" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                <h6 class="overlay-text-clr">@a.profilename</h6>
                            </div>
                        }
                        if (i == 4)
                        {
                            <div class="hoverchilddiv bg-img4">
                                <img class="" src="~/Files/ProfilePics/@a.profilepic" width="80" height="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                <h6 class="overlay-text-clr">@a.profilename</h6>
                            </div>
                        }                          


                }


                }

            </li>
        </ul>
```

in the above code we've used a for loop to give the unique css to each data set, but we dint get the expected result.

following are the CSS classes for the above html code

```
.bg-img1 {
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
z-index: 99;
margin-left: -129px;
```

}

```
.bg-img1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.7);
    z-index: 99999;
}


.bg-img2 {
margin-left: -79px;
margin-top: 49px;
z-index: 99;
```

}

```
.bg-img2:hover {
    transform: scale(1.7);
}

.bg-img3 {
margin-left: -186px;
margin-top: 55px;
z-index: 99;
```

}

```
 .bg-img3:hover {
    transform: scale(1.7);
}

.bg-img4 {
margin-left: -134px;
margin-top: 107px;
z-index: 99;
```

}

```
.bg-img4:hover {
    transform: scale(1.7);
}
```

Comment: I might be blind but your classes look identical with no changes during the loop.You already have the index counter `i`. append that to the class name and delete the rest of the `if` statements

Comment: Hi Gezzasa, we've updated the code with the different CSS classes. Can you pls recheck it.

Comment: what do you mean that it doesn't work. Can you add your CSS as well? The number you can replace with the `i` index counter in the loop. Your current loop as is is a bit redundant in my opinion.

Comment: So, issue might be with your styling. What do you want to achieve? What should the final product look like?

Comment: @Adarsh have you considered using [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) instead of margin for positioning? I think you'll find it's a much better way to position things.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a counter:

```html
@{
  int counter = 1;                                         @* set a counter *@
  foreach (var a in Model.publicShowModelProfileForUI)
  {
        <div class="hoverchilddiv bg-img@counter">         @* use the counter for your class *@
            <img class="" src="~/Files/ProfilePics/@a.profilepic" width="80" height="80" />
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-text">
            <h6 class="overlay-text-clr">@a.profilename</h6>
        </div>

      counter++;                                             @* increment the counter *@
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use a for loop? You won't need an extra var then.

Comment: No as you are just putting your var into the for loop and then you would have to do additional calculations like `i+1` as the loop will be 0 based on the index and then you would have to access each item using `a[i]` which isn't as nice to maintain as using the actual object